# Spring Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I had a Spring boot project that I wrote earlier and I try to re-run it today. I get the error telling me Unable to acquire JDBC Connection through the username and password was correct. The full error stack is provided below,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ef.Parser.main(Parser.java:46) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.ef.service.LogEntityServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$574ab47e.saveAllLogEntities(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ef.Parser.run(Parser.java:105) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'logparser'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

The app starts from the `Parser` file provided,

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ef.repository")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.ef"}, exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Parser implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Autowired
    private IpAddressService ipAddressService;

    @Autowired
    private HttpInfoMessageService httpInfoMessageService;

    @Autowired
    private LogEntityService logEntityService;

//    @Autowired
//    private IpService ipService;

    public Parser() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Parser.class);
        application.run(args);
    }

    /*
    * print all the IP addresses that is over the threshold
    * with all the http messages
    * */
    public static void printIpsAboveThresholdWithHttpMessages(List<IpAddress> ipAddresses) {

        System.out.println("  IP      :      COMMENT  ");
        ipAddresses.forEach(ipAddress -> {
            ipAddress.getHttpInfoMessage2s().forEach(
                    httpInfoMessage -> {
                        System.out.println(ipAddress.getAddress() + " : " + httpInfoMessage.getStatus());
                    }
            );

            System.out.println();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        /*Options options = new Options();

        Option start = new Option("startDate", "startDate", true, "Start date");
        start.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(start);

        Option duration = new Option("duration", "duration", true, "duration");
        duration.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(duration);

        Option threshold = new Option("threshold", "threshold", true, "threshold");
        threshold.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(threshold);

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        CommandLine cmd;

        try {
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            formatter.printHelp("utility-name", options);

            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }

        String startDate = cmd.getOptionValue("startDate").trim().replace(".", " ");
        String dur = String.valueOf(cmd.getOptionValue("duration")).trim();
        int thers = (int) Integer.valueOf(cmd.getOptionValue("threshold").trim());*/

        List<LogEntity> allRecords = FileManager.readFileByLines("Log.txt");

        // save all the log entities to the MySQL database
        logEntityService.saveAllLogEntities(allRecords);

        List<IpAddress> ipAddresses = DataOrganizationHelper
                .getIpAddressesFromAllRecordsWithDurationAndThresHold(allRecords, "2017-10-02 17:14:55",
                        "daily", 100);

        // some experiment
//        List<Ip> ips = DataOrganizationHelper.getIpFromAllRecordsWithDurationAndThresHold(allRecords, "2017-10-02 17:14:55",
//                "daily", 100);
//        System.out.println("The size is = " + ips.size());
//        ipService.saveAllIps(ips);

        printIpsAboveThresholdWithHttpMessages(ipAddresses);

        // save the ip addresses and the http messages to the MySQL database
        ipAddressService.saveAllIpAddressses(ipAddresses);

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The `application.properties` file is provided,

```
spring.application.name=Wallethub Log Parser

# MySQL configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/LogParser
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# database username and the password
spring.datasource.username=testuser
spring.datasource.password=testpassword

# for the console app
spring.main.web-environment=false
spring.main.banner-mode=off


# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I used Spring earlier, but, haven't touched it for a while. What is the issue I miss? If anyone interested, the full code is [here](https://github.com/Chaklader/Spring-Log-Parser).

Comment: You trace mentioned : Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'logparser' ,
check once if it exists as db name is case sensitive

Comment: do I need to manually create the database? As far as I can remember, the app creates the database itself. I could be surely wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Unknown database 'logparser'

Apparently, it cannot find the database which the name is `logparser` . You have to manually create the database upfront first. `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` will only create tables for you. It will not create a database.

Comment: Is there any way to create the `LogParser` database at the time app is started? It should check if the database exists and if not only then it will create.

Comment: Of course you can but not through Hibernate. You can simply use JDBC to create a database if it does not exist. Just make sure this process is executed before bootstrapping Hibernate